# Rewrite rules for apache write

Tags: apache, http, server, url-rewriting, rules

I have this url :

```
https://dnsdo.org/index.php?url=LK37919018653819
```

I need to make like this

```
https://dnsdo.org/LK37919018653819
```

Can anyone help to make rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```